# query separar datos por meses

Tags: sql

hola a todos estoy realizando el sigueinte query donde queiro que me devuelva los movimientos por Item que se tuvieron durante un rango de fechas, pero separado por mes

algo asi

->  ITEM

->  ENTRADA ENERO

->  SALIDA ENERO

-> ENTRADA FEBRERO

-> SALIDA FEBRERO

-> ENTRADA MARZO

-> SALIDA MARZO

ECT.....

este es mi codigo actual

```html
SELECT T1.Item_No,T1.Description,T1.Min_Quantity,T1.Max_Quantity,

case WHEN T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1  THEN SUM(T3.Quantity) END as Recividos,

case WHEN T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 3  THEN SUM(T3.Quantity) END as Entregados,

MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) as MES

FROM Purchasing_v_Item T1

INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Usage_e T3 ON T1.Item_Key = T3.Item_Key

WHERE T3.Usage_Date BETWEEN '1/01/2019' AND '10/03/2019' AND Item_No LIKE '%RPROD000%'

GROUP BY T1.Item_No,T1.Description,T1.Min_Quantity,T1.Max_Quantity,T3.Transaction_Type_Key,MONTH(T3.Usage_Date)
```

el problema es que no esta agrupando por mes,este es el resultado que actual mente tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la consulta ya agrupas por meses: `GROUP BY ... MONTH(T3.Usage_Date)` ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: no los esta agrupando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres una columna independiente por mes, puedes aplicar una suma condicional de esta forma:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 1 
              AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Recibidos_Enero
```

Dentro del  `SUM()` incorporamos el `CASE` y obviamente ya no podemos agrupar mas por mes ya que el éste se usa dentro de la suma para poder hacer caer `Quantity` en la columna que le corresponde.

Otro problema en tu consulta es `T3.Transaction_Type_Key`, si lo tienes como parte del `GROUP BY` no podrás separar cada tipo en distintas columnas, deben ir dentro de la función de agregación.

```
SELECT  T1.Item_No,
    T1.Description,
    T1.Min_Quantity,
    T1.Max_Quantity,

    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 1 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Recibidos_Enero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 1 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 2 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Entregados_Enero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 2 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Recibidos_Febrero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 2 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 2 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Entregados_Febrero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 3 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Recibidos_Marzo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) = 3 AND T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 2 THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Entregados_Marzo

    FROM Purchasing_v_Item T1
    INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Usage_e T3 ON T1.Item_Key = T3.Item_Key
    WHERE   T3.Usage_Date BETWEEN '1/01/2019' AND '10/03/2019' 
        AND Item_No LIKE '%RPROD000%'

    GROUP BY T1.Item_No,
        T1.Description,
        T1.Min_Quantity,
        T1.Max_Quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes mal acomodadas las funciones de agregado. Las funciones deben rodear la expresión CASE para poder agrupar correctamente. Con eso, también debes quitar Transaction_Type_Key del GROUP BY. Además, puedes agregar un ELSE para eliminar los valores nulos.

```
SELECT T1.Item_No,
    T1.Description,
    T1.Min_Quantity,
    T1.Max_Quantity,
    SUM(case WHEN T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 1  THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) as Recibidos,
    SUM(case WHEN T3.Transaction_Type_Key = 3  THEN T3.Quantity ELSE 0 END) as Entregados,
    MONTH(T3.Usage_Date) as MES
FROM Purchasing_v_Item T1
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_Item_Usage_e T3 ON T1.Item_Key = T3.Item_Key
WHERE T3.Usage_Date BETWEEN '1/01/2019' AND '10/03/2019' 
AND   T1.Item_No LIKE '%RPROD000%'
GROUP BY 
    T1.Item_No,
    T1.Description,
    T1.Min_Quantity,
    T1.Max_Quantity,
    MONTH(T3.Usage_Date)
```

Comment: muchas gracias. y si quiero que me muestre todos los meses aun que en ese mes no tenga ningun movimiento

Comment: Para eso primero necesitas combinar todos los artículos  con todos los meses mediante un cross join. Después unes el resultado de esa consulta al resultado de esta con un left join.